# Test cases are getting skipped because of the below error mentioned in description

Tags: appium

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void loadSystemProperties()' of abstract class org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:504)
at org.epg.utils.AppiumUtils.startAppiumServer(AppiumUtils.java:56)
at org.org.TestUtils.AndroidBaseTest.ConfigureAppium(AndroidBaseTest.java:53)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Tried updating TestNG and Appium dependencies

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.